# widget not appearing

Tags: android, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to make a widget, but when I install my app it doesn't appear in the list of  Widgets, I assume that means that there is something wrong with my manifest file. Have tried several different examples all for 1.5-2.2, is there something different between the way re-honeycomb and post-honeycomb Widgets work?

Anyways this is the widget section of my manifest

```
    <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
    <receiver android:name=".ButtonWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

        <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will also process our self created action -->
        <action android:name="com.dotpubs.counterpro.ButtonWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/button_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <!-- this activity will be called, when we fire our self created ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE -->
    <activity android:name=".ClickOneActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.dotpubs.counterpro.ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: Not all of the code is showing, I don't know why, when I try to edit it is shows, can anyone help with that?

Comment: Pay attention to LogCat when you run the app and maybe there is a log message that will tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you are running Android 4.0.3?

There is a known problem in that version. See [issue 24208](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24208)